# Function to convert data retrieved from Zend_table to html entities

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

i'm using zend_tables for my model and i'd like to create a function to convert all data from a single row (retireved like this: $row = $model->find($id))  to htmlentities before outputting it with the usual code:

```
echo ($row->current()->nameOfField);
```

I need something like this function i use on arrays:

```
public static function convertArrayToHtmlEntities($data){


        $keys = array_keys($data);

        foreach ($keys as $k) {


            $d = $data[$k];

            $clean = htmlentities($d, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

            $data[$k] = $clean;
        }


        return $data;
    }
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: Why not just convert zend_db_row to array `$row->toArray()`, and use your function?

Comment: Actually i also have a function that decodes objects...i could cycle on row->current() and convert everything, i just wanted to be sure to convert only properties of $row->current() and not other parts!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Zend View you can just escape the output in your view script.  See [Escaping Output](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.view.scripts.html#zend.view.scripts.escaping).

If you're not using it in a view script you can use [Zend Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.htmlentities).